# Padrino app not loading custom helpers when deployed to tomcat windows 7

Tags: tomcat, jruby, padrino, warbler

I have a padrino app developed using jruby on linux, which works fine.  However when I deploy it to Tomcat on Windows 7 using warbler, I get the following error when accessing a page:

```
undefined local variable or method `authenticate' for #<MyApp:0x480ebb>
file: app.rb 

C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/theapp/WEB-INF/app/app.rb in MyApp
authenticate 
C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/theapp/WEB-INF/gems/gems/padrino-core-0.12.2/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb in filter!
    base.filters[type].each { |block| instance_eval(&block) }
```

Here is the offending line in app/app.rb:

```
class MyApp < Padrino::Application
  # lots of standard code
  register Padrino::Helpers

  before do
    authenticate 
  end
end
```

And this is the helper file: app/helpers/auth_helper.rb.  (Originally the helper was declared with `MyApp.helpers do`, I tried changing it to a module but with no luck).

```
class MyApp
  module AuthHelper

    def logged_in?
      session[:user].present?
    end

    def authenticate
      if !logged_in?
        # Allow login page to be seen
        allowed_urls = ['/','/login', '/account/activate', '/account/register']
        return if allowed_urls.include? request.path_info
      end

      if logged_in?
        @user = session[:user]
      else
        redirect to('/login') 
      end
    end

    def logout  
      @user = nil  
      session.clear if logged_in?
      redirect to('/login') 
    end
  end

  helpers AuthHelper
end
```

Update: I never worked out why I couldn't get tomcat to work with my app, and it wasn't replicated by a person from the padrino community.  I moved to Jetty which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you define `authenticate` in controller or related model file.
A `Helper` method is provided for rendering html, and if you want to use a helper method, you should `include HelperModule` first.

Comment: ```include HelperModule``` just produces an uninitialized constant error.  I do have ```register Padrino::Helpers``` in app.rb.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this error by putting the `authenticate` call after the helper code in the auth_helper.rb file:

```
class MyApp < Padrino::Application

  # Pre / Post Filters
  before do
    authenticate 
    @breadcrumbs = [{label: 'Home', href: '/'}]
  end
end
```

Now I get nothing but 404's in tomcat, so I'm not sure this has actually worked.